# Dual of a vector space of dimension one

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

It is a standard linear algebra result that a vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{K}$ is isomorphic to its dual $V^{\vee}$, but non canonically in general. If $V = \mathbb{K}$ then we have a canonical isomorphism:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{K}^{\vee} @>>> \mathbb{K} \\
\\
\lambda @>>> \lambda(1)
\end{CD}
$$

My question is: can this argument be extended to the vector spaces of dimension one?

Comment: A vector space of dimension one is isomorphic to its base field, but not canonically. When trying to extend this argument to a vector space of dimension one, which vector should you take in place of $1$? This comes down to a choice of basis, which is what makes the isomorphism non-canonical just as for higher-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @Servaes: I thought it couldn't be possible, but I thought would have been sensible trying to ask. Thank you!

Comment: @Will R: Thank you, I edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vector space of dimension one is isomorphic to its base field, but not canonically. When trying to extend your argument to a vector space of dimension one, which vector $v\in V$ should take the place of the $1$ in
$$\Bbb{K}^{\vee}\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{K}:\ \lambda\ \longmapsto\ \lambda(1)?$$
This comes down to choosing a basis for $V$, which is what makes the isomorphism non-canonical just as for higher-dimensional vector spaces.